# routes.MapRoute - Redirect from /pageA to controller pageB - Make it SEO friendly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-routing

What I am trying to do is to use routes.MapRoute in order to redirect from pages such as /colorful-rainbow so that then the request goes to /TheColorfulRainbowController.

In short I am trying to implement a SEO friendly set of URLS for my domain for which the requests will then go to the pertinent controller in my backend code.

So far what I have seen are pretty simple samples of routes.MapRoute on how to redirect somewhere if no controller is specified, or how to redirect somewhere else if no action is specified, and so on if no further parameter is specified.. but not like : if this url comes to you, go to this controller.

This is what I have seen :

```
    //AUTO ROUT TO LOAD
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}/{lname}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Load", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
            name = UrlParameter.Optional, 
            lname = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }
    );
```

Can anybody give me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can define verbatim template and specify desired controller as default.  E.g.:

```
//AUTO ROUT TO LOAD
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "colorful-rainbow/{action}/{id}/{name}/{lname}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "TheColorfulRainbow",
        action = "Load", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        name = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        lname = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```